# sitecore 8 item created time is returning different time

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

In item's statistics section the created time is 15:19 but item.Statistics.created gives 14:19 am. A time difference of 1 hour is there. How can I get time that is shown in Statistics section?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The date which Sitecore saves in the database is always ISO Date. There are many options you can use to get your local time.

E.g. you can use `ToLocalTime()` method of `DateTime`, so:

```cs
item.Statistics.Created.ToLocalTime()
```

Or when you get a value from a field:

```cs
var dateField = (DateField)item.Fields["Date"];
var itemDate = Sitecore.DateUtil.IsoDateToDateTime(dateField.Value);
```

You can also look at other methods of `DateUtil` class, like `ToServerTime()`.